# REGEX - extrair parte do texto em uma string

Tags: python, regex

eu tenho a seguinte string ==> *"o cara da pamonha bateu com o carro no carro de fulano"* eu estou querendo extrair comecando de ^("o cara ...") e terminando em ("... o carro")$ alguem poderia me ajudar com essa **RE**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se o objetivo é só selecionar esse pedaço vc poderia ir direto ao ponto:

```
/o cara da pamonha bateu com o carro/
```

Ou pode usar esse padrão:

```
/o cara(.*)no carro/
```

Veja o [exemplo](https://regex101.com/r/sW6jZ9/1).

---

UPDATE

Então se vc quer parar na primeira palavra "carro" e retornar tudo desde o início da frase use esse padrão:

```
/^(.*?)carro/
```

[Exemplo](https://regex101.com/r/sW6jZ9/2)

Comment: essa pergunta e so uma ilustracao do meu real problema e exite uma importancia de portugues na string eu quero que o meu regex termine na primeira palavra carro e nao na segunda palavra carro olha o que aconteceu i.stack.imgur.com/QzoJS.png

Comment: Não entendi o que exatamente vc quer extrair? Pode dar mais detalhes?

Comment: @MagicHat na minha string tem duas palavra **carro**. eu quero que a minha re termine na primeira ocorencia da palavra **carro**

Comment: Bota a re que se já tentou e o erro que tá dando...

Comment: veja o update que fiz

Comment: resolveu seu problema?

Comment: @zwitterion positivo! obrigado pela prestatividade :)